# Merge 2 arrays by appending values

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have 2 arrays

```
$a = array('v1'=>1,'v2'=>2,'v3'=>3,'v4'=>4);

$b = array('v1'=>1,'v2'=>2,'v3'=>3,'v4'=>5);
```

How do I merge them to a single array like this :

```
Array
(
    [v1] => 1
    [v2] => 2
    [v3] => 3
    [v4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
        )
)
```

I have tried using `array_merge` & `array_merge_recursive`.

Comment: I don't think there's any built-in command that does what you want in a shot...

Comment: I am not looking for one either, I am just looking for the shortest way possible.

Comment: oh ok, try Samy's solution then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
$a = array('v1'=>1,'v2'=>2,'v3'=>3,'v4'=>4);
$b = array('v1'=>1,'v2'=>2,'v3'=>3,'v4'=>5);
$c = array();
foreach($a as $m => $n) {
   if (($b[$m] != $n))
      $c[$m] = array($n, $b[$m]);
   else
      $c[$m] = $n;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$result = array_intersect_assoc($a, $b);

foreach (array_diff_assoc($a, $b) as $k => $v)
  $result[$k] = array($v, $b[$k]);
```

**Update:**
anubhava's solution is good. It can be simplified like this:

```
$c = array();
foreach($a as $k => $v) 
  $c[$k] = $b[$k] == $v ? $v : array($v, $b[$k]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = array('v1'=>1,'v2'=>2,'v3'=>3,'v4'=>4);
$b = array('v1'=>1,'v2'=>2,'v3'=>3,'v4'=>5);
$results = array();

foreach ($a as $key=>$elem) {
  $results[$key][] = $elem;
  if (!in_array($b[$key], $results[$key])) {
    $results[$key][] = $b[$key];
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah sorry, didn't notice that.

Comment: still not, see @anubhava's solution